# Using Bootstrap Modals to represent a external HTML file

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have tried looking into setting up Bootstrap modals as external html files so I can show other websites I've made inside of the one website but couldn't really find anything that works with modals. Is this even possible or am I supposed to use a jQuery popover style method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then using an `iFrame` just use the following solution.

Fist visit [this link](http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/). And see section with label 'Loading remote page (1)'.

You can always use this bootstrap-dialog method to populate popup any time and any situation. and also you can customize popup however you want

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving it and for those that possibly have the same issue, I solved it using an iframe reference inside the modal-body and stretching the iframe to fit the modal